# Can't re-enable Windows Defender service even as administrator

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I found that my Windows Defender settings were disabled, saying 'managed by organization', so I followed [this guide](https://blog.pcrisk.com/windows/12584-some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization-how-to-fix) to fix it (essentially getting rid of the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender` key and subkeys. 
After a reboot, Windows Defender is still unable to start the service. A look at the service dialog and this is what I see:

[image: This is while running as administrator, goes without saying]

The same problem for the related `Windows Defender Antivirus Network Inspection Service`. How do I fix this?

**Edit** - I found this in the event log -

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Launch
>   permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
>   `Windows.SecurityCenter.WscBrokerManager`  and APPID  `Unavailable`  to
>   the user `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18)` from address LocalHost
>   (Using LRPC) running in the application container `Unavailable` SID
>   `(Unavailable)`. This security permission can be modified using the
>   Component Services administrative tool.

I opened the Component services tool, but there's no mention of this component, and I don't know how to use this.

Comment: Can you set the Start DWORD to 3 under: set:`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinDefend` then restart the computer.  I assume it's then started even if you can't change it from services.msc.

Comment: It got changed to 'manual', and when I open security center I'm back to square one - 'all settings managed by organization', and under `gpedit.msc` _everything_ has been verifiably set to 'not configured'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to try :

- If you have installed any third-party anti-virus, uninstall, reboot and try again.
  See [this list](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/antivirus_removal_tools)
  for more thorough removal tools.
- Start an elevated Command Prompt (cmd) and run the command:

  ```
  sc start WinDefend Enable
  ```
- Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- Start Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`), navigate to *Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Defender*,
  double-click *Turn off Windows Defender*, and set to *Not Configured*
- Start an elevated Command Prompt (cmd) and run the following commands:

  ```
  regsvr32 wuaueng.dll
  regsvr32 wucltui.dll
  regsvr32 softpub.dll
  regsvr32 wintrust.dll
  regsvr32 initpki.dll
  regsvr32 wups.dll
  regsvr32 wuweb.dll
  regsvr32 atl.dll
  regsvr32 mssip32.dll
  ```

  You may use the free [FixWin](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fixwin-for-windows-10)
  to do that, using its option
  "Repair Windows Defender. Reset all Windows Defender settings to default".
- In case of an an inconsistent WMI repository, run the command:

  ```
  winmgmt /verifyrepository
  ```

  If you get a message “WMI repository is not consistent“, run the following command:

  ```
  winmgmt /salvagerepository
  ```
- Start a Command prompt (cmd) as SYSTEM using
  "[psexec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) -sid cmd.exe",
  launch `services.msc` from it, and the *Startup type* drop-down should
  now become enabled.
- Run deep anti-virus scans by several well-known anti-virus products.
  Many of these products offer online one-time scans.
- As last resort,
  [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Before starting, ensure you have very good backups.

---

Edit:

Regarding the specific error message you found in the log,
it seems like it's not a serious problem, but can be avoided.

The [thread](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/109079-event-id-10016-distributedcom-windows-securitycenter-wscbrokermanager-2.html)
says this :

> The problem in this case is that the service for Windows SecurityCenter (wscsvc) have a delayed autostart while "things" like the WscBrokerManager and WscCloudBackupProvider tries to initiate very early in the startup process. It will fail with error event 10016. wscsvc will initiate after ~2 minutes and then everything will be instantiated as normal so you will have no side effects of these errors in the event log but it's annoying.
>
> You solve this by changing the service wscsvc from delayed autostart to normal autostart. You don't (normally) have permission to do it from the services app so you must do it in the registry.
>
> ```
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wscsvc
> ```
>
> Change the DWORD `DelayedAutoStart` from 1 to 0.

Try this fix, maybe it has some more effects than it seems.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps.
- Not using any 3rd party AV, sfc reported no problems and I had already reset group policy to nil.
- WMI repository is reported consistent.
- psexec trick worked, now was able to make the service startup automatically, but I can't start it from there(1053: service did not respond in a timely fashion).
But after all this, when I click the button in Defender Security Center to restart the threat service, it again reports an 'unexpected' error.

Comment: I have added two more steps, which I hoped wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I found something else in the event log..have updated the question.

Comment: What is the event id?

Comment: I added to my answer.

Comment: Yup, the event ID was 10016. Let me try this.

Comment: Didn't work. Also have set ownership on the CLSID for Defender in the registry so I could fix permissions with dcomcnfg, and now even after changing service type to automatic, 'the service didn't respond in a timely fashion'.

Comment: I think you are getting closer to my above last resort measure.

Comment: Decided to just get Kaspersky instead. Lo and behold, it found a bunch of malware.

Comment: That was my before-last item.

Comment: Yep, marking this as the answer. I think I'll stick with Kaspersky, not sure if removing it will re-enable Defender or I'll be stuck with the permissions thing again. I'd gotten along fine with just Defender so far, now have to rethink it.

Comment: If your computer has been successfully cleaned, you could try without Kaspersky.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I will do that. I've not used any antivirus since MSE was launched for WIndows 7 about 5 years ago.

Comment: You should also spend some time on your other defenses, especially in the browser, to avoid being re-infected.

Comment: Uninstalled Kaspersky, and it's back to the same problem. I usually stick to Pale Moon, a Firefox fork, but had to use Chromium for a few sites. Behold, everything Kaspersky found was from Chromium's cache. Chrom(e/ium) is the new IE.